# How to properly link libc++ and libz in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm pretty new to XCode and I tried to link libc++ and libz in XCode, under `Build Settings - Other Linker Flags`, but when I add a new line that says `libc++` or `libz`, I get an error stating `no such file or directory libc++`

I also tried by adding `libc++.dylib` and `/usr/lib/libc++.dylib`, but still the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

> [EDIT]

I get this in the error message:

```
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.
platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

And this:

```
/-weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit
/-weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia
/-weak-lSystem -ObjC libc++.tbd -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime
/-framework Fabric -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Crashlytics
/-framework Security

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'libc++.tbd'
```

Is that being linked correctly?

Comment: Have you tried adding `libc++.tbd` and `libz.tbd`?

Comment: I just did and seem to get the same error, can the linking paths not include the libc++ path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured that out by myself, I had to add them using the `Link Binary With Libraries` option under `Build Phases`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html